# Drawing a commutative diagram with LaTeX

Tags: commutative-diagrams

How can i write the LaTeX code of the figure given below: [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please show us what you've tried so far. Please also tell us which document class you employ and which drawing-related packages, if any, you load.

Comment: My document class is article and i have used grapxix and Tikz package.

Comment: `tikz-cd` is the popular package to draw these

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Percusse's comment, you can start with this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=2cm]
A\arrow[r,"\text{inclusion}"] \arrow[rd, swap,"\varphi"] & F(A) \arrow[d,"\Phi"] \\
                                                         & M
\end{tikzcd}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

giving:

[image]

Comment: `\arrow[rd,swap,"\varphi"]` will move the phi to the other side. Also `\arrow[rd,"\varphi"']` would work, but it's less readable.